# Selenium Form Submission

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, webforms

I am trying to automate a form submission using selenium. But JavaScript that runs upon clicking sign-on is causing Exception invoking submit. Selenium is directing the submit to localhost, not to the form action. Can anyone explain why is this happening and kindly provide a solution on how to overcome this.

Here is the form :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <title>Sign On</title>
    <base href="https://machine.place.domain.com:9031/"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css"/>
</head>
<body onload="setFocus()">
<div class="container signin">
    <div class="header">
        Sign On
    </div>
    <div class="body-container">
        <div class="section-title">
            Please sign on and we'll send you right along.
        </div>
        <div>
            <form method="POST" action="/idp/L0YZK/resumeSAML20/idp/SSO.ping" autocomplete="off">
                <div class="messages">                       
                </div>
                <div class="input-label">
                    Username
                </div>
                <div class="input-container">
                    <input id="username" type="text" size="36" name="pf.username" value="" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" onKeyPress="return postOnReturn(event)" placeholder="Username" /><!---->
                </div>
                <div class="input-label">
                    Password
                </div>
                <div class="input-container">
                    <input id="password" type="password" size="36" name="pf.pass" onKeyPress="return postOnReturn(event)" placeholder="Password" />
                </div>              
                <div class="buttons">
                    <input type="hidden" name="pf.ok" value=""/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="pf.cancel" value=""/>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="postCancel();" class="button blue deny" title="Cancel">
                        Cancel
                    </a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="postOk();" class="button normal allow" title="Sign On">
                        Sign On
                    </a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-container">
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="credits">
                <a href="http://www.example.com">Example</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function postOk() {
        document.forms[0]['pf.ok'].value = 'clicked';
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }
    function postCancel() {
        document.forms[0]['pf.cancel'].value = 'clicked';
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }
    function postOnReturn(e) {
        var keycode;
        if (window.event) keycode = window.event.keyCode;
        else if (e) keycode = e.which;
        else return true;
        if (keycode == 13) {
            document.forms[0].submit();
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    function setFocus() {
        var platform = navigator.platform;
        if(platform != null && platform.indexOf("iPhone") == -1) {
                            document.getElementById('username').focus();
                    }
    }
    function setMobile(mobile) {
        var className = ' mobile',
            hasClass = (bodyTag.className.indexOf(className) !== -1);
        if(mobile && !hasClass) {
            bodyTag.className += className;
        } else if (!mobile && hasClass) {
            bodyTag.className = bodyTag.className.replace(className, '');
        }      
            }
    function getScreenWidth() {
        return (window.outerHeight) ? window.outerWidth : document.body.clientWidth;
    }
    var bodyTag = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
        width = getScreenWidth(),
        remember = false && false;
    if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        setMobile(true);
    } else {
        setMobile((width <= 480));
        window.onresize = function() {
            width = getScreenWidth();
            setMobile((width <= 480));
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Java Code :

```
    private final static String PF_BASE_URL = "https://machine.place.domain.com";
    private final static String PF_PRIMARY_SSL_PORT = "9031";
    private final static String PF_START_SSO_ENDPOINT = "/sp/startSSO.ping";
    private final static String PARTNER_ENTITY_ID = "LDAPTest:SAML2:IDP";
try{
    DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
    capability.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(capability);
    driver.get(PF_BASE_URL + ":" + PF_PRIMARY_SSL_PORT + PF_START_SSO_ENDPOINT + "?" + "PartnerIdpId="+ PARTNER_ENTITY_ID);
    HtmlUnitWebElement formElement = (HtmlUnitWebElement) driver.findElement(By.tagName("form"));
    String actionURL = formElement.getAttribute("action");
    String newactionURL = PF_BASE_URL + ":" + PF_PRIMARY_SSL_PORT + actionURL;
    String script = "document.forms[0].action='"+newactionURL+"'";
    if(driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor){
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script);
    }
    HtmlUnitWebElement usernameElement = (HtmlUnitWebElement) driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
    usernameElement.sendKeys("user");
    HtmlUnitWebElement passwordElement = (HtmlUnitWebElement) driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
    passwordElement.sendKeys("password");
    List<WebElement> anchors = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    for (int i = 0; i < anchors.size(); i++) {
        String title = anchors.get(i).getAttribute("title");
        if (title.equalsIgnoreCase("Sign on")) {
                anchors.get(i).click();
                break;
            }
    }
    driver.close();
} catch (Exception e){
System.out.println(e.tostring());
}
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Exception invoking submit
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: '********', ip: '***********', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_40'
Driver info: driver.version: HtmlUnitDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.executeScript(HtmlUnitDriver.java:683)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitWebElement.submitForm(HtmlUnitWebElement.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitWebElement.submit(HtmlUnitWebElement.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitWebElement.submit(HtmlUnitWebElement.java:184)
    at WasteClass.main(WasteClass.java:61)
Caused by: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Exception invoking submit
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:847)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:513)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:779)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:751)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunctionIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:1008)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.executeScript(HtmlUnitDriver.java:677)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Exception invoking submit
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:847)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:513)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:779)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:751)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunctionIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:1008)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeEventHandler(EventListenersContainer.java:234)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeBubblingListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:254)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventTarget.fireEvent(EventTarget.java:186)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement$1.run(HtmlElement.java:923)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:513)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.fireEvent(HtmlElement.java:928)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeEventHandlersIfNeeded(HtmlPage.java:1316)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.initialize(HtmlPage.java:286)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:478)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadDownloadedResponses(WebClient.java:2110)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.doProcessPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:875)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.access$500(JavaScriptEngine.java:104)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:842)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Exception invoking submit
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:847)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:513)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:779)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:751)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunctionIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:1008)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeEventHandler(EventListenersContainer.java:234)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeBubblingListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:254)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventTarget.fireEvent(EventTarget.java:186)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement$1.run(HtmlElement.java:923)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:513)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.fireEvent(HtmlElement.java:928)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeEventHandlersIfNeeded(HtmlPage.java:1316)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.initialize(HtmlPage.java:286)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:478)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadDownloadedResponses(WebClient.java:2110)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.doProcessPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:875)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.access$500(JavaScriptEngine.java:104)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:842)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception invoking submit
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:181)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:449)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1536)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventHandler.call(EventHandler.java:82)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:411)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:309)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3286)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$4.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:772)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:832)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:80 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.download(WebClient.java:2054)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.html.HTMLFormElement.submit(HTMLFormElement.java:355)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:153)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:80 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:151)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getResponse(HttpWebConnection.java:184)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1316)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1233)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.download(WebClient.java:2050)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:74)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
    ... 76 more
```

Answer (score 2):

From the Selenium [wiki](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver):

> None of the popular browsers uses the javascript engine used by HtmlUnit (Rhino). If you test javascript using HtmlUnit the results may differ significantly from those browsers.

In other words: if you rely on JavaScript, do not use HtmlUnit. If you need a headless browser, consider [PhantomJS](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver).

Comment: I did not use PhantomJS and I stuck to htmlunit. Selenium somehow started posting to form's action and localhost. I did not change my environments configuration or change the code posted above. Issue solved by itself. Sigh..

Comment: @Raavi _Magic gnomes_. ;)